# Render glyphs only from specified font

Tags: javascript, css

I have this HTML

```
<div style="font-family: Arial">&#32768;!</div>
```

`&#32768;` is a CJK ideograph and my Arial font doesn't contain the glyph for it. But Chrome renders it.

When I look at Web Inspector > Computed styles > Rendered Fonts, I see:

```
Arial — 1 glyph
Droid Sans Japanese — 1 glyph
```

Chrome uses Droid for the ideograph.

What I need is this:

1. If a specified font doesn't contain the glyph, don't render the symbol, or
2. Have JavaScript get me the rendered font (instead of the unused font I set)

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("my-div"), null).fontFamily;
```

returns `Arial`.

Comment: I have reformatted your question a bit. I hope I haven't messed up anything. Cheers!

Comment: if a font doesn't contain the glyph to be rendered, it will automatically fall on the next font set in the element `font-family` set in CSS, then to os ones. You can then either set the wanted font as the second one of your `font-family` declaration, or create a font which will treat this glyph as empty if you don't want it rendered at all (but then why include it in your markup?). However, I'm unsure how to get the retained font for each character...

Comment: potatopeelings, Kaiido, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put [Adobe Blank](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-blank) in the font-family after the font you want to see, and then any glyphs not in that font won't be rendered.

e.g.:

```
font-family: Arial, 'Adobe Blank';
```

If you want to test it in JS you could render individual glyphs with a font-family including Adobe Blank and measure their width to see if it is zero, but you'd have to iterate thorough each glyph and each font you wanted to test.

As far as I'm aware there is no JS method to tell which glyphs are being rendered by which font in the element's font stack (i.e. more than one font in the stack. e.g. "Arial","Segoe UI Symbol","Adobe Blank"). I'd love to be proved wrong though.

---

If all you are looking for is a way to see what glyphs are in a particular font:

- **on windows** you can use [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) to inspect fonts installed on the system
- or **online** you can upload a font to [Opentype's Glyph inspector](https://opentype.js.org/glyph-inspector.html)